# Conflicts with phonegap app development - Android and Windows

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on a phonegap project - started with my webapp.
My webapp is prepared using HTML5, CSS3, Jquery (1.9.), Jquery Mobile (1.3.0) and Javascript functions.... integrated with PHP for MySQL database.
This webapp when deployed in Eclipse, as per phonegap's documentation, is generating the .apk with expected output on the emulator/device.

When I used the same webapp and deployed on Windows phone 7 using VisualStudio 2010 as per phonegap's documentation, the app is not working on a windows phone emulator/device.

The UI part is fine but no Javascript function is working on windows platform.

Are there any pre-requisites/conditions/procedures for windows platform to work for a phonegap project? Please help me out on this issue. I have a requirement to build apps using phonegap on all major platforms - android, windows, blackberry and IOS.

Comment: Did you use the version of `cordova.js` for windows phone 7?

Comment: @ranjjose - yeah it's 2.6 am using now. Followed the instructions as given in 2.6 version's documentation of phonegap.

Comment: no one here who has a solution? ??!?!?!

Comment: There are no prerequisites for windows phones it should just work. But as that's obviously not the case, I'd suggest that there maybe some kind of JavaScript error that only affects windows. Do you have an event listener on the window.error event to capture such errors and log them to the console? You could also try opening up your HTML page in Internet explorer which would give you access to the developer tools and help validate your JavaScript.